# How to include navigation properties of a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In my base repository I have a method which takes includes as expression

```cs
public T MyFunction(my parameters..., params List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>[] includes)
foreach(var setOfIncludes in includes)
{
    foreach(var include in setOfIncludes)
    {
        query = query.Include(include);
    }
}
```

For these models:

```
Users         
navigation property: List<Car> cars
Car 
navigation property: Make make
Make
```

for a User, I want to include both the cars and their makes using EF Core 6.

With my current setup, is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks.

Example:
I tried to include it like this

```cs
var includes = new List<Expression<Func<User, object>>>
{
    x => x.Cars,
    x => x.Cars.Select(c => c.Make)
};
```

but I get an error saying that the second Include is not valid.

Comment: You're basically trying to do what EF already does for you. If your context is scoped, just return an IQueryable and let the dev handle the conditions.

Comment: @GHDevOps check my exmaple please

Comment: The method with expression list does not work with EF Core, because EF Core uses/requires different pattern - `Include`/`ThenInclude` calls which cannot be represented with expression list.

Comment: context.Set<T>().AsQueryable() will do exactly what you want. Then you can use it like: Get<Car>().Include(i => i.Make).Include(i => i.Model).Where(w => w.Id == myId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: Why not use `ThenInclude` method?  here is an example same to yours  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager